# Bash script to go through directories and find files and rename them

Tags: bash

I want to go to every folders and find a file (file.sum) in each folder. If the file exist, I want to rename to indicate folder where it come from (i.e. 265.file.sum and then move it to a different folder (let's call it ~/summary).. The folder names are using 3 digit number from 001 to 365. Number of folders are not necesary 365. It could be 250 or 100.
How do you do it using bash script?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `for file in [0-9][0-9][0-9]/file.sum; do mv "$file" ~/summary/"${file/\//.}"; done`

Comment: Nice one liner script! I am not quite understand "${file/\//.}" part, but it works! Thank you!

Comment: `${file/\//.}` is to replace first `/` in $file by `.`

Comment: Got it. Thank you, Nahuel!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bash-only. Assumes you are in the directory where the `###` folders are and your target directory already exists in `$some_path`.

```
for f in [0-9][0-9][0-9]/file.sum
do d="${f%/*}"  # current immediate folder name
   n="${f##*/}" # basename
   mv "$f" "$some_path/summary/$d.$n"
done
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I tested this script on dummy folders and it works like a charm.

Comment: You're quite welcome. Glad to help. Any questions on the logic?

Comment: Your script is quite easy to understand for a beginner like me. Thanks, Paul!

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
for f in $(find path/to/search -name "file.sum") 
do 
   mv "$f" ~/summary/$(dirname "$f").$(basename "$f") 
done
```

Comment: This script will rename and move file.sum from any directories in the search path [not only from 001-365 folders]. Thanks!